# Why is my program throwing an exception?

Tags: java, arraylist, exception

Whats happening is when I try to add a new class to my student, I have to check to make sure that the class time I am trying to add doesn't conflict with my students other class times, but for some reason when the code gets into the loop to check the other course times stored in an array list, there is an exeption called when their shouldn't be. For example, I could put in 5:00p-10:00p for one course, then 1:00p-2:00p for the second course and it will throw the exception like there is a conflict there when there isn't. please check the comment to see where the problem occurs. any ideas?

```
package myschool;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MySchool {
private static Exception e;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Student> listStudent = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> listCourseStart = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> listCourseEnd = new ArrayList<>();

    boolean continueLoop = true;
    boolean addFirstCourse = true;
    boolean addACourse = false;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    int option;

    do{
    try {  
    System.out.println(" What would you like to do?");
    System.out.println(" 1) Add a student");
    System.out.println(" 2) View students");
    System.out.println(" 3) Remove a student");
    System.out.println(" 4) Exit");
    System.out.print("--> ");
    option = userInput.nextInt();

    switch( option ){
            case 1:
                Scanner inputs = new Scanner(System.in);
                String fName, lName;
                int sID;
                double sGPA;

                System.out.print(" First Name:");
                fName = inputs.nextLine();

                System.out.print(" Last Name:");
                lName = inputs.nextLine();

                System.out.print(" ID Number:");
                sID = inputs.nextInt();

                System.out.print(" GPA:");
                sGPA = inputs.nextDouble();

                Student newStudent = new Student(fName, lName, sID, sGPA);
                listStudent.add(newStudent);

                inputs.nextLine();

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Would you like to add a course? Y/N");
                        String shouldAddCourse = inputs.nextLine();

                        if( "N".equals(shouldAddCourse.toUpperCase()))
                                       break;

                        System.out.print(" CourseName:");
                        String cName = inputs.nextLine();

                        System.out.print(" Instructor:");
                        String instructor = inputs.nextLine();

                        System.out.print(" CourseID:");
                        int cID = inputs.nextInt();

                        System.out.print(" CourseCredit:");
                        int cCred = inputs.nextInt();
                        inputs.nextLine();

                        System.out.print(" StartTime:");
                        String cStart = inputs.nextLine();
                        System.out.print(" AM or PM ?");
                        String startAMorPM = inputs.nextLine();

                        System.out.print(" EndTime:");
                        String cEnd = inputs.nextLine();
                        System.out.print(" AM or PM ?");
                        String endAMorPM = inputs.nextLine();

                        String cStartRemove = cStart.replace(":","");
                        int startInt = Integer.parseInt( cStartRemove );

                        String cEndRemove = cEnd.replace(":","");
                        int endInt = Integer.parseInt( cEndRemove );

                        if( "PM".equals(startAMorPM) || "pm".equals(startAMorPM) || "P".equals(startAMorPM) || "p".equals(startAMorPM) )
                            startInt = startInt + 1200;

                        if( "PM".equals(endAMorPM) || "pm".equals(endAMorPM) || "P".equals(endAMorPM) || "p".equals(endAMorPM) )
                            endInt = endInt + 1200;

                        if( addFirstCourse ){
                            Course newCourse = new Course( cName, instructor, cCred, cStart, cEnd, cID );
                            newStudent.listCourse.add(newCourse);
                            listCourseStart.add( startInt );
                            listCourseEnd.add( endInt );
                            addFirstCourse = false;
                        }else{     

                        for( Integer r: listCourseStart ) {
                            if( startInt >= listCourseStart.get(r) && startInt <= listCourseEnd.get(r) /*|| endInt >= listCourseStart.get(r) && endInt <= listCourseEnd.get(r)*/ ) //the problems happens hear on the first listCourseStart.get(r)
                                throw e;
                            else
                                addACourse = true;
                        }

                        if( addACourse == true ){
                            listCourseStart.add( startInt );
                            listCourseEnd.add( endInt );
                            Course newCourse = new Course( cName, instructor, cCred, cStart, cEnd, cID );
                            newStudent.listCourse.add(newCourse);
                            addACourse = false;
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("You have already added a class at that time!");
                    }
                }
                break;


            case 2:
                if(!listStudent.isEmpty()){
                    for(Student l:listStudent) {
                        System.out.println(l);
                        for(Course n:l.listCourse) {
                            System.out.println(n);
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }


                }else
                System.out.println("There are no students to view\n");

               break;

            case 3:
                Scanner removeChoice = new Scanner(System.in);

                try {
                    if(!listStudent.isEmpty()){
                    int j = 0;
                    System.out.println("Which student do you want to remove?");

                        for(Student l:listStudent) {
                            System.out.print(j+1 + ")");
                            System.out.println(l);
                            j++;
                        }
                        int remove = removeChoice.nextInt();
                            listStudent.remove( remove - 1 );
                        System.out.println("Student has been removed\n");
                    }else
                        System.out.println("There are no students to remove\n");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("There are no students to remove\n");
                }

                break;

            case 4:
                continueLoop = false;
                break;
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid option!!!");
        continueLoop = false;
    }

    }while( continueLoop );
}
```

}

Comment: what exception you get? and where?

Comment: Its the exception I created. It throws exception e, which says "You have already added a class at that time!"

Comment: Then you should show us the code where is the throw new {...}

Comment: It throws an exception because you told it to throw an exception.

Comment: I wrote on there to look for the comment!

Comment: Scroll the window to the far right then scroll down you'll see it

Comment: You CANNOT see the comment unless you scroll the code window all the way over.  How is someone supposed to know that you put a comment out there?

Comment: Missing some source files that I couldn't infer from just making a constructor.

Comment: You catch the _real_ Exception and call a `System.out.println(...)`. It would be necessary if you call an `exception.printStackTrace()` inside your catch-block

Comment: talk to stack overflow about that, how would I know that??

Comment: Aha, just now i noticed the line... but why? We are too lazy to scroll the code view. Anyway i don't see anything wrong, check your if and make sure its what you want.

Comment: Marco, these guys are giving me shit because I didn't make it easy enough to see but when I pasted it into the window earlier the text wrapped to the next line so you could see it then when I posted it looked like this. How the heck would I know that??? Anyway yeah the code looks fine to me, but for some reason its still thawing that exception.... I doubled checked the if statement and its how its supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

You're throwing an exception in your for loop.

```
for( Integer r: listCourseStart ) {
    if( startInt >= listCourseStart.get(r) && startInt <= listCourseEnd.get(r) /*|| endInt >= listCourseStart.get(r) && endInt <= listCourseEnd.get(r)*/ ) //the problems happens hear on the first listCourseStart.get(r)
        throw e;// <-- This guy is the culprit, but I'm guessing you already knew that...
    else
        addACourse = true;
}
```

It's fairly difficult to say exactly where it's going wrong (it's a bit hard to read your code, but it *should* be behaving as you've stated).

You may want to use some breakpoints, if you're using an IDE, and check the values of your input variables before they get put into the list, or have it spit them back out at you on the command line, before putting them in the list.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that, I created that to throw the exception in the event that the student tries to add a course into a time that is already created. So if the logic of the if-statement is true it will throw the exception, if its false it will continue on and add a course, but its not making it past the first part "startInt >= listCourseStart.get(r)"

Comment: I figured you did, I was just making some edits, and thinking over what more I'd add to it :P

Also, wouldn't it need to get past both the startInt >= listCourseStart.get(r) AND startInt <= listCourseEnd.get(r) to get into that if statement?

Comment: its weird because the values are all correct, I can see the variable values in the debugger as I go, and I also printed them out after I went through converting them to military time instead of String

Comment: It's because you're pulling the "rth" member of the list with "get(r)".  You should just check the value against r.  Unless your students have over 1300 classes, I don't think that would work out too well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your loop

```
for( Integer r: listCourseStart ) { // r ist the value in listCourseStart
    // you use the value 'r' as index
    // you have to use for( int i = 0; i.....) or 'r' is the the right value
    if( startInt >= listCourseStart.get(r) && startInt <= listCourseEnd.get(r) ) 
        throw e;
    else
        addACourse = true;
}
```

Try this

```
for( Integer r: listCourseStart ) {
    if( startInt >= r && startInt <= r ) 
        throw e;
    else
        addACourse = true;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Yout are right in your comment. Your condition is not necessary. You need to store the start and end time together. Here is an exsample:

```
List<Integer[]> times = new ArrayList<>();
times.add(new Integer[]{900,1100});
times.add(new Integer[]{1300,1400});
for( Integer[] time : times ){
    if( startInt >= time[0] && startInt <= time[1] 
         || endInt >= time[0] && endInt <= time[1] ){
        throw e;
    }
}
```

A little Hint: Your Exception `e` was never initiate - you will get a NullPointerException

Comment: Ok so this is really close, the only problem now is that id doesn't throw the exception:/

Comment: This actually doesn't make sense, how could startIn be >= to r while simultaniously be <= r?

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the list `listCourseStart` in the for loop.

```
for( Integer r: listCourseStart ) {
  if( startInt >= listCourseStart.get(r) && startInt <= listCourseEnd.get(r) )                                     
    throw e;
  else
    addACourse = true;
}
```

`listCourseStart` is a list of intergers and with

```
for( Integer r: listCourseStart ) {
  // ...
}
```

you iterate over the list elements. So in the first iteration `r` will be the first list element, in the second iteration the second list element and so on.

But inside your loop you call `listCourseStart.get(r)`. The list's `get()` method retrieves the list element at the given position. So if the first list element is 5 then with `listCourseStart.get(5)` you get the fifth list element. I'm sure, this is not really what you want.

Why didn't you use a debugger? You can run your program step by step, it shows you the actual variable values so you can see what's going on in detail.

Comment: I need it to iterate from the beginning of the list to the end which changes depending on the amount of courses added. so it would need iterate through each list for start/end to check. Woulnt r increase from 0-numOfListElements which would allow it to scroll through all the possible options?

Comment: If you want to access the list by position then you should use a different form of a for loop: `for(int r = 0; r < listCourseStart.size(); r++) { ... }`. If you are confused about the different forms of Java for loops, read this for clarification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html